# when using swagger codegen getting 'List<byte[]>' instead of simply 'byte[]'

Tags: swagger, maven-plugin, swagger-codegen

A byte[] is modelled in swagger file as an Array of `byte[]`. When using swagger codegen we are getting `List<byte[]>` instead of simply `byte[]`

Swagger.json

```
"document": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": 
    {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "byte"
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger.json</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
                <configOptions>
                   <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 9):

The issue is in generating the swagger.json file ie the maven plugin swagger-maven-plugin.
The correct swagger.json file for a byte[] should look like:

```
"document": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "byte"
 }
```

In order to achieve this we have to add custom ModelConvertors exactly as shown in below link:
https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/422

Also add ModelConvertors tag in the project pom file with the path to the location of your custom modelconvertor.

Note: There is no change in swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.

Comment: What do we have to do in case of a `StreamingResponseBody`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080432/how-to-declare-binary-data-response-content-type-correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` for **OpenAPI v.2** json file then response with byte[] return type looks like this:

```
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "byte[] return example for swagger: 2.0",
    "schema": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "byte"
    }
  }
}
```

And response for **OpenAPI v.3** looks like this:

```
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "byte[] return example for openapi: 3.0",
    "content": {
      "*/*": {
        "schema": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "byte"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```