# How to define byte array in OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: java, spring, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm migrating my API from Swagger 2.0 to OpenAPI 3.0. In a DTO I have a field specified as a byte array.
Swagger definition of the DTO:

```
Job:
   type: object
   properties:
       body:
         type: string
         format: binary
```

Using the definition above the swagger code generator generates an object that accepts `byte[]` array as the body field `new Job().setBody(new byte[1])`.

After converting the API definition to OpenAPI the definition for that object stayed the same but the openapi code generator now requires `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` instead of `byte[]` (`new Job().setBody(org.springframework.core.io.Resource)`). There are some places in my code where I have to serialize the Job object but it's no longer possible because `Resource` doesn't implement serializable.

As a workaround I changed the type to `object`:

```
Job:
   type: object
   properties:
       body:
         type: object
```

Now I have to cast the body to `String` and then convert to `byte[]` everywhere and I'd rather have the type as `byte[]` as it was before.

How can I specify the type as `byte[]` using OpenAPI 3.0?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must set type: string and format: byte

Original answer: [when using swagger codegen getting 'List<byte[]>' instead of simply 'byte[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010889/when-using-swagger-codegen-getting-listbyte-instead-of-simply-byte)