# OpenApi documentation converts byte[] in array of byte[]

Tags: java, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I generate a Java class from a YAML file describing the model with `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>document-10-service</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/openapi/server/v1.0/documents-1.0.yaml</inputSpec>
          <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/document-10-service</output>
          <generateApis>true</generateApis>
          <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
          <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
          <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
          <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
          <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
          <apiPackage>com.siemens.spice.documents.generated.api</apiPackage>
          <modelPackage>com.siemens.spice.documents.generated.model</modelPackage>
          <invokerPackage>com.siemens.spice.documents.generated</invokerPackage>
          <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
          <skipOverwrite>false</skipOverwrite>
          <configOptions>
            <sourceFolder>server</sourceFolder>
            <supportingFiles>ApiUtil.java</supportingFiles>
            <library>spring-boot</library>
            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
            <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
          </configOptions>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
```

I have the following model described in the YAML file:

```yaml
 Document:
required:
  - documentMetaData
  - documentContent
type: "object"
properties:
  documentMetaData:
    $ref: "#/definitions/DocumentMetaData"
    description: "Document type information"
  documentContent:
    type: string
    format: byte
    description: "Base64 encoded document content"
```

This generates the following class which is ok:

```java
public class DownloadDocument   {
  @JsonProperty("documentMetaData")
  private DocumentMetaData documentMetaData;

  @JsonProperty("documentContent")
  private byte[] documentContent;
}
```

But when entering the `swagger-ui.html` page and trying to get the documentation by click on the link:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntqPY.png)

it looks like this:

```yaml
"DownloadDocument": {
            "required": [
                "documentContent",
                "documentMetaData"
            ],
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "documentMetaData": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DocumentMetaData"
                },
                "documentContent": {
                    **"type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "byte"
                    }**
                }
```

The document content which is a `byte[]` is documented as an array of `byte[]` and when using this description in other app to generate an API client it generates a `List<byte[]>`.

I would expect the following format also in the OpenApi Specification/Description:

```yaml
documentContent:
    type: string
    format: byte
    description: "Base64 encoded document content"
```

Can you please advice if this is a bug or if not how can be resolved?

Comment: I am using the following versions: 
<springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.5.9</springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
    <swagger-annotations.version>1.5.22</swagger-annotations.version>and 
 <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>

Comment: did I understand properly that you generate java api using openapi spec, and then openapi-ui generates openapi spec using java api? O_o. BTW, there was a bug in openapi-ui [String with format byte (base64) is being an array of strings and not a string #1559](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1559)

Answer (score 1):

If you have generated Java classes from a YAML file the Swagger UI should generate the origin YAML/JSON file.

**Known Issues**

There are several issues for [OpenAPI Tools](https://github.com/openapi-tools):

- [OpenApi documentation converts byte[] in array of byte[]](https://github.com/openapi-tools/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/81)
- [byte[] not correctly handled by openapi converter](https://github.com/openapi-tools/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/22)

There are also several issues for [SpringFox](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/):

- [Response with a byte array does not work as expected](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1605)
- [byte array should have type string and format byte](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1430)
- [swagger-codegen-cli.jar dont understand ResponseEntity<byte[]>](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1439)

There are also issues for [springdoc-openapi](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi):

- [String with format byte (base64) is being an array of strings and not a string](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1559)

Other implementations with issues:

- [byte[] operation responses / model properties modelled incorrectly](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/422)

**Known work-arounds**

- If you could change the Java classes, see 
  [byte[] not correctly handled by openapi converter](https://github.com/openapi-tools/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/22#issuecomment-648135222)
  :

  > Just for reference, if you want to use the io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations, then use this:
  >
  > ```
  >  @ApiResponse (description = "default response",
  >           content = @Content (schema = @Schema (type = "string",
  >                                                 format = "byte")))
  > ```

  There is also a solution for non response type, see 
  [String with format byte (base64) is being an array of strings and not a string](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1559#issuecomment-1073062930)
  :

  > ```java
  >  @Schema(name = "message",  required = true, type = "string", format = "binary")
  >  @JsonProperty("message")
  >  @lombok.Builder.Default
  >  @NotNull
  >  private byte[] message = null;
  > ```
- If you could use Maven Plugin instead of Swagger UI to generate your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file, see [Response with a byte array does not work as expected](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1605#issuecomment-276910444)
  :

  > I encountered a similar issue using the swagger maven plugin (from kongchen).
  > I fixed it by defining an additional ModelConverter that verifies if it's a byte[] and then returns a ByteArrayProperty:

  There is also a solution for request parameter, see [byte[] operation responses / model properties modelled incorrectly](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/422#issuecomment-575614391):

  > It does this for Request bodies as well. Here is the fix for version 2.0.10:

**Related questions**

- [How to declare binary data response content-type correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080432/how-to-declare-binary-data-response-content-type-correctly)
- [when using swagger codegen getting 'List<byte[]>' instead of simply 'byte[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010889/when-using-swagger-codegen-getting-listbyte-instead-of-simply-byte)
- [How to define byte array in OpenAPI 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794949/how-to-define-byte-array-in-openapi-3-0)