# How to declare binary data response content-type correctly?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

For a web application I am working on, I need to fetch some binary (meta) data for an audio file.

This is how the endpoint looks like:

```java
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/tracks/{trackId}/metadata",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
)
@ApiResponse(
        description = "Successful Operation", 
        responseCode = "200", 
        content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
)
public StreamingResponseBody getTrackMetadata(@PathVariable("trackId") Long trackId) {

    TrackEntity track = this.trackService.getTrack(trackId);
    String bucketName = track.getBucketName();
    String bucketFilename = track.getBucketFilename();

    return outputStream -> {

        final int headerSize = 4; // FIXME Get this from file ..

        InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = this.trackService
                .readChunk(bucketName, bucketFilename, 0);

        try (InputStream inputStream = inputStreamResource.getInputStream()) {
            StreamUtils.copyRange(inputStream, outputStream, 0, headerSize);
        }
    };
}
```

And these are the generated signatures for the endoint:

```js
/**
 * @param trackId
 * @param observe set whether or not to return the data Observable as the body, response or events. defaults to returning the body.
 * @param reportProgress flag to report request and response progress.
 */
getTrackMetadata(trackId: number, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<any>;
getTrackMetadata(trackId: number, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>;
getTrackMetadata(trackId: number, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
```

However, as I try to load the data, I receive a `HttpErrorResponse`:

```
Http failure during parsing for https://192.168.178.25:8443/api/tracks/1/metadata
```

Which reveals that the client tries to parse the data as JSON:

```
Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0↵    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
   at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:30205:51)
   ...
```

It seems that the generated client code is not aware of the fact that the data is not JSON format.

I have also tried to set `content` of `@ApiResponse` to

```java
content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format= "byte"))
```

but the result is the same.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not to bring an old post back to life, but did you ever find an answer to this? I'm trying to document a protobuf returning API and I have the same problem. This is what I have for my return type `@OpenApiResponse(status = "200", content = {@OpenApiContent(type = "application/x-protobuf", isArray = true, from = byte[].class)})`

Comment: @TheFunk Just checked my old proect and I'm afraid I never found a solution for that. I guess I implemented a workaround. Can't recall exactly but from what I see I wasn't able to make it work that way. I'd recommend checking out github issues for OpenAPI or create one for this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just change your

```
content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
```

to

```
content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format= "byte"))
```

Whole part that works for me:

```
@GetMapping(value = "getStoredFile/{id}",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ApiResponse(
        description = "File found and delivered",
        responseCode = "200",
        content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format= "byte"))
)
@ResponseBody
public StreamingResponseBody getStoredFile(@PathVariable String id) {
//your code here ...
```

Comment: OP said they tried the solution you describe here _long before you posted it_.

Comment: If you check, it is NOT the same. I provided the working example. His example did not work for me either.